Creating a round capped brush in JavaFX
I am currently in the process of creating a paint application using JavaFX. I currently have a paint function (called squiggle) that takes in an array of points from mouse events and creates line segments that connect each of these points. This was fine at first when I was only dealing with 1px line segments. I have since implemented a stroke width changer using GraphicsContent.setStroke(), which has highlighted the fact that the line segments are naturally rectangular in shape. This causes the lines, especially when using a thicker stroke width, to come out very fuzzy and generally odd.
My idea was to create an array of circles out of the points, to give it a more authentic brush feel, but this didn't work as the circles weren't connected and left very large gaps in between each point.
When I tried to connect each circle with a line segment, it will just return to the same problem as before as the rectangles usually out shadow the circle.
I have also attempted to use path, which I've never tried before. This just leads me back to the same original problem, but now I experience more delay while drawing. This could be the fact that I am implementing it wrong, but at this point, I'm not even sure if path will help me.
Here is my toPath method within the Squiggle class:
public Path toPath(){
    Path path = new Path();
    path.setStroke(this.getColor());
    path.setStrokeWidth(this.getStrokeWidth());
    path.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);

    if (this.points.isEmpty()) {
        return path;
    }

    Point start = this.points.getFirst();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(start.x, start.y));

    for(int i = 1; i < this.points.size(); i++){
        Point point = this.points.get(i);
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(point.x, point.y));
    }
    return path;
}

Here is the update method in my paint panel:
GraphicsContext g2d = this.getGraphicsContext2D();

for(Squiggle sq: squiggles){
    Path path = sq.toPath();
    if (!path.getElements().isEmpty()){
        for (var element : path.getElements()) {
            if (element instanceof MoveTo moveTo) {
                g2d.moveTo(moveTo.getX(), moveTo.getY());
            } else if (element instanceof LineTo lineTo) {
                g2d.lineTo(lineTo.getX(), lineTo.getY());
            }
        }
    
        g2d.stroke();
    }
}

Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to try something else?

I may be misunderstanding the problem, but perhaps setLineCap is what you're looking for? Possibly setLineJoin as well?

It was, in fact setLineCap. I went back to my original method of using an array of points. Thanks!

You aren't drawing a Path node
A Path is a node, which will be rendered by the JavaFX system when placed in the scene graph.  But your node in the scene graph is a GraphicsContext, which is the only thing rendered.
You use Path as a data holder, manually rendering it in your GraphicsContext via GraphicsContext commands. You don't apply all attributes of the path (the stroke and linecap) to the graphics context.
How to apply the additional Path properties to your GraphicContext
You write:
path.setStroke(this.getColor());
path.setStrokeWidth(this.getStrokeWidth());
path.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);

To apply those properties to a GraphicsContext (gc), you could write:
gc.setStroke(path.getStroke());
gc.setLineWidth(path.getStrokeWidth());
gc.setLineCap(path.getStrokeLineCap());

See the documentation of GraphicsContext for a description of these methods and any other graphics methods you might need to get the effect you desire.
For example, you can also invoke setLineJoin on your graphics context, as mentioned by Slaw in comments.
gc.setLineJoin(path.getStrokeLineJoin());

Suppose your input model data isn't rich enough to define attributes on strokes such as caps and joins. In that case, you can default the assumed appropriate values for those in your code (e.g. StrokeLineJoin.ROUND and StrokeLineCap.ROUND).  This will round the ends of a path, and the places where the path elements join each other.
Alternate Implementation
Instead of creating the commands to render a GraphicsContext yourself, you could use a Pane, placing the Path in the SceneGraph by adding it as a child of the Pane.  But that is a completely different approach I won't discuss further here.
You could probably use a Polyline rather than a Path, but both would probably work.
